# How to compare two timestamps without seconds?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I have two timestamps: one from `time()` function, other selects user in front-end. I need to compare this two timestamps, but ignore the seconds or set it to 00. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: can you show the user provided time or the code or anything that make this question more interesting ..

Comment: If you want to ignore the seconds, just replace the last 2 numbers with 0?

Comment: Classic "what have you tried?"

Answer (score 1):

Had some time for an example:

```
$nr = 1111111122;

$nr = substr($nr, 0, strlen($nr)-2) . "00";
```

Answer (score 0):

echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:00', time()));